# Empty output file (flush() and close() already added)

Tags: java, io

Im trying to write an output file from the following code. The file is successfully created but it remains empty. I have tried finding how to solve this problem and I read that I have to add flush() or close(). I have tried to put the flush() and close() in the code but it is still not working and I cant seem to figure out why.

Below is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Citation2{

    String title;
    String author;
    String year;
    String conference;
    String index;
    String cite;
    String abstracts;
    String Line;
    private final Path fFilePath;
    private final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;  

    public static void main (String[] args) throws SQLException,
    ClassNotFoundException, IOException{

        Citation2 parser = new Citation2("D:/test.txt");
        parser.processLineByLine();

    }

    public Citation2(String aFileName){
        fFilePath = Paths.get(aFileName);
    }

    public final void processLineByLine() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try (Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(fFilePath, ENCODING.name())){
            String nextLine = null;
            if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            while (nextLine!=null){
                nextLine = processLine(nextLine, scanner);
            }      
        }
    }

    protected String processLine(String aLine, Scanner scanner) throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String nextLine = null;
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("D:/output.txt");


        try{
            if (aLine.startsWith("#*")) {
                title = aLine.substring(2);
                Line = title;
            } 
            else if (aLine.startsWith("#@")){
                author = aLine.substring(2);
                Line = Line + "\t" + author;
            }
            else if (aLine.startsWith("#t")){
                year = aLine.substring(2);
                Line = Line + "\t" + year;

            }
            else if (aLine.startsWith("#c")){
                conference = aLine.substring(2);
                Line = Line + "\t" + conference;
            }
            else if (aLine.startsWith("#index")){
                index = aLine.substring(6);
                Line = Line + "\t" + index;
            }
            else if (aLine.startsWith("#%")){
                cite = aLine.substring(2);
                while(scanner.hasNextLine() && (nextLine = scanner.nextLine()).startsWith("#%"))
                {
                    cite += "," + nextLine.substring(2); 
                }   
                Line = Line + "\t" + cite;

                out.write(Line);
            } 
            if(nextLine== null && scanner.hasNextLine()){
                nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            }       
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
        }
        finally{
             out.flush();
             out.close();
        }
        return nextLine;
    }
```

And I tried this also but it is not working as well.

```
  else if (aLine.startsWith("#%")){
                    cite = aLine.substring(2);
                    while(scanner.hasNextLine() && (nextLine = scanner.nextLine()).startsWith("#%"))
                    {
                        cite += "," + nextLine.substring(2); 
                    }   
                    Line = Line + "\t" + cite;

                    out.write(Line);
                    out.flush();

                } 
                if(nextLine== null && scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
                }       
            }
            catch(Exception e){ 
            }
            finally{
                 out.close();
            }
            return nextLine;
        }
```

And some said I can use `out.println()` since it automatically flush but it also not working.

The input file is as follows:

```
#*A strategy for acquiring customer requirement patterns using laddering technique and ART2 neural network.
#@Chun-Hsien Chen,Li Pheng Khoo,Wei Yan
#t2002
#cAdvanced Engineering Informatics
#index743424
#% 
#!

#*Usable autonomic computing systems: The system administrators' perspective.
#@Rob Barrett,Paul P. Maglio,Eser Kandogan,John H. Bailey
#t2005
#cAdvanced Engineering Informatics
#index743458
#%121622
#%635878
#%806957
#%892618
#!

#*Ant colony optimization techniques for the vehicle routing problem.
#@John E. Bell,Patrick R. McMullen
#t2004
#cAdvanced Engineering Informatics
#index743464
#% 
#!
```

When I tried System.out.println() it gives me the output that I want which is as follows:

```
A strategy for acquiring customer requirement patterns using laddering technique and ART2 neural network.   Chun-Hsien Chen,Li Pheng Khoo,Wei Yan   2002    Advanced Engineering Informatics    743424   
Usable autonomic computing systems: The system administrators' perspective. Rob Barrett,Paul P. Maglio,Eser Kandogan,John H. Bailey 2005    Advanced Engineering Informatics    743458  121622,635878,806957,892618
Ant colony optimization techniques for the vehicle routing problem. John E. Bell,Patrick R. McMullen    2004    Advanced Engineering Informatics    743464
```

Comment: You shouldn't leave the `catch` phrase empty. There may be an exception that you're not aware of. At the very least use e.printStackTrace().

Comment: Debug it, make sure the `out.write(Line)` line is called.

Comment: Tried e.printStackTrace but no exception on the program.

Comment: @hagubear what effect can `flush` have after the file has been `close`d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are creating a new PrintWriter and writing each line and closing it. This will override the previousr writes. So I have moved the PrintWriter creation to only one.

```
public final void processLineByLine() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    try (Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(fFilePath, ENCODING.name())){
        String nextLine = null;
        if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("D:/output.txt");
        while (nextLine!=null){
            nextLine = processLine(nextLine, scanner, out);
        } 
        out.close();
    }
}

protected String processLine(String aLine, Scanner scanner, PrintWriter out) throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String nextLine = null;

        if (aLine.startsWith("#*")) {
            title = aLine.substring(2);
            Line = title;
        } 
        else if (aLine.startsWith("#@")){
            author = aLine.substring(2);
            Line = Line + "\t" + author;
        }
        else if (aLine.startsWith("#t")){
            year = aLine.substring(2);
            Line = Line + "\t" + year;

        }
        else if (aLine.startsWith("#c")){
            conference = aLine.substring(2);
            Line = Line + "\t" + conference;
        }
        else if (aLine.startsWith("#index")){
            index = aLine.substring(6);
            Line = Line + "\t" + index;
        }
        else if (aLine.startsWith("#%")){
            cite = aLine.substring(2);
            while(scanner.hasNextLine() && (nextLine = scanner.nextLine()).startsWith("#%"))
            {
                cite += "," + nextLine.substring(2); 
            }   
            Line = Line + "\t" + cite;

            out.append(Line);
        } 
        if(nextLine== null && scanner.hasNextLine()){
            nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
        }       
    return nextLine;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical error in your program:

- You open and close the file once per line of the input file, instead of opening before the first line and closing after the last line.

Note: the name of the `Line` variable should not start with a capital letter.

There is no need to use `flush()` in your program. `close` flushes all buffer before it closes the stream/writer.

Comment: When I used System.out.println, I got the output that I want (question is updated). The reason I write it when the operation line starts with #% is to retrieve the output I want. I'll try to fix the logical error that you mentioned. Thanks